# How to only UPDATE certain attributes from a Database dump(sql/text/csv or any other format)

Tags: database, postgresql, insert-update, dbeaver, data-recovery

I have a specific requirement of extracting data from certain columns of a table(for certain records, identified by a Unique ID) AND update the records with same ID in another table with same values in a column.

Database I am using is Postgresql. I wish if there is a way through extracting using a database tool(DBeaver, PG Admin, etc) with which I can extract from one DB and save values in another DB. I tried extracting values from DBeaver but they were `Insert INTO` statements, would create duplicate records.

The layman solution I have is to extract in a CSV and then update the records by reading row-by-row through a Rake task.

Any help for suggesting a solution the DB level way is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have 2 Questions 1. Whether it is an one time task or a recurring task? 2. your dump file is a SQL dump or csv of a single table

Comment: @AkhileshMishra 1) It is a One time task, launch of a feature which involves creation of new tables, and alongside adding values to it as well. | 2) It can be any based on how we extract it from DBeaver, can be a CSV can be a SQL file, although that is part of question that which format could it be.

Comment: Whether Both DB's can communicate with each other?

Comment: We can make them communicate, but only if necessary as one if production and one is a Demo for Customers(a copy of Production though).

Comment: Then below solution will work perfectly and efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

By using [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/postgres-fdw.html) you can achieve this very easily. Please Follow below mentioned steps on your new database where you want to update the table:

Step - 1: Create Extension

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
```

Step - 2: Create Remote Server

```
create server remote_server
foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
options(host 'remote_server', dbname 'remote_dbname', port '5432');
```

Step - 3: Create Foreign User Mapping for the server

```
create user mapping for localuser
server remote_server
options(user 'remoteuser', password 'remoteuser_password');
```

Step - 4: Create Foreign Table with same structure as in remote DB

```
create foreign table "schema_name"."remote_table"
(
id_ int;
...
-- field list same as foreign table in other db
)
server remote_server
options(SCHEMA_NAME 'foreign_schema', TABLE_NAME 'foreign_name');
```

Now you can use `local_table_name` in your query just as local table but It will do all operations on remote db.

Your update query can be written like below:

```
update local_table p1
set 
-- your set statements
.....
.....
from remote_table p2
where p1.id = p2.id;
```

you can drop the `remote_table` if you feel it is not required in future.

**Note: -** Above will work only if both databases are on same server or both database can communicate with each other (if on different server).

Answer (score 1):

I found I could do that in an older version of DBeaver (7.1.3) but not in newer ones.
If you run a script "select column1, column3,... from your_table" asking for the data of the columns you need, then you right-click on the results and the menu that opens will let you generate sql->update with just the fields from the results of your select.
I don't know why they took this pretty useful feature from the new versions. Maybe there's another way now but I couldn't find it.